# How to remove default date format from kendoui.min.js

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendoui datepicker into inline grid,So i want to change default date format of min.js file . format like `yyyy/mm/dd` so please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: When it post grid data in the json format it change date format.

Comment: you mean while sending the grid data it is formatting in some other format?

Comment: Yes sir ,after post it contain post date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly provide the format like

```
$('#datePicker').kendoDatepicker({
 format: "yyyy/MM/dd"
});
```